# Pandas group_by date and resample

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data frame that looks like this:

```
    A   B   C   date
0   J   Y   2   2013-02-01 14:21:02.070030
1   X   X   0   2013-02-01 15:49:33.110849
2   Y   D   9   2013-02-01 06:47:19.369514
3   Y   C   17  2013-02-01 08:56:11.751781
4   3   J   21  2013-02-01 14:19:12.017232
```

I'd like to group by date and then count, but omit the information about the hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

It seems like something like this works:

```
df.set_index('date').resample('D').count()
```

Two questions:

1. Why does that work? Is that the right way?
2. Why doesn't something like `df.group_by('date').resample('D').count()` work?

Comment: 1. Because `resample` works with time indexes. And yes, that's the right way.
2. Something like `df.group_by('date').resample('D').count()` would not work because you need time indexing for sampling to work.
You can do something like: `df.set_index('date').resample('D').count().reset_index()` to still keep `date` as a column.

Answer (score 4):

`resample` is in some sense just a special case of groupby - rather than grouping on distinct values, which is what `grouppy('date')` would do, it groups a time-based transformation of the index, which is why you need to set the index.  Alternatively, you could do:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D')).count()
```

In the upcoming version `0.19.0` you'll be able to write the above like this.

```
df.resample('D', on='date').count()
```

Comment: When I tried your suggestion of pd.Grouper, I got the following error: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: @Huey you need to ensure your date column is a `date_time` column.  It's reasonable for us to assume it is, considering it's a date.  do conversion with `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)` then apply chrisb's answer.  Then check off this as the chosen answer because it's a great answer ;-)

Comment: I did use pd.to_datetime and I sitll could not get this to work.